# Proper way of doing predictions in Bayesian linear Model

Tags: regression, bayesian, linear

I'm working on a Bayesian linear model with student scores as response variable and a set of predictors. My model is:

$Y_{i} = \beta*X + \epsilon_i$

$i = 1,...,n $

$\beta$ ~ $N(0,\Sigma)$

$\epsilon_i$ ~ $N(0,\sigma^2)$

$\sigma^2$ ~ $inv-gamma(a,b)$

Having a training set and a test set I was wondering which was the best way to make predictions and assess my results. I considered the following:

1. Consider the posterior mean of $\beta$, say $\beta_m$ and calculate $E[Y]$ = $X_{test}*\beta_m$ , completely ignoring the variance (this is done in R through blinregexpected in LearnBayes package).
2. Sampling many times from the predictive distribution $L(Y_{new}|Y_{train})$ and see if the real value $Y_{test_i}$ falls in a 90% Credible interval, if so I guessed it right. (Done in R through blinregpred)
3. Your suggestions.

I actually did the above obtaining very similar results.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: please help me understand concept of beta and gamma here. areyou working on a probablistic model or fixed effects model.

Comment: $\beta$ are the regression coefficients, $\sigma^2$ is the residual variance. I chose a normal prior for $\beta$ and an inverse-gamma for $\sigma^2$ so that the model is conjugate and posterior inference is easier.

Comment: No mixed effects in this model.

Comment: I guessed number 2. is more appropriate to check outliers